# Large numerical errors in my Mathematica program

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, precision, numerical

Here is a piece of my program. Have a look.

```
For[m = 1, m <= mode1, m++,
  For[n = 0, n <= mode2, n++,
    A[m, n][t_] = a[m, n]*Cos[\[Omega]*t];
    B[m, n][t_] = b[m, n]*Cos[\[Omega]*t];
  ]
]

temp = 0;
For[m = 1, m <= mode1, m++,
  For[n = 0, n <= mode2, n++,
    temp++;
    equation[temp] = 
      ExpandAll[Integrate[eqC[m, n]*Cos[\[Omega]*t], {t, 0, (2*Pi)/\[Omega]}]];
    equation[temp] = ExpandAll[Simplify[equation[temp]/10^9]];
    Print["\n\nEquation ", temp, "-\n", equation[temp]];
    temp++;
    equation[temp] = 
      ExpandAll[Integrate[eqS[m, n]*Cos[\[Omega]*t], {t, 0, (2*Pi)/\[Omega]}]];
    equation[temp] = ExpandAll[Simplify[equation[temp]/10^9]];
    Print["\n\nEquation ", temp, "-\n", equation[temp]];
  ]
]
```

After running of this code I am supposed to get few equations and then create a matrix out of it by a series of differentiations. I know that the matrix must come out to be symmetric. The problem is that when I enter simple data i.e. e=1,h=1, etc. I get accurate results and the matrix is symmetric, but as soon as I give the real data which have values like 71.02e9,0.000247 the calculations come out to be wrong and I get an unsymmetric matrix. I have thoroughly checked the code and cannot find a single mistake on my part. I have also checked the results of the program for a simple case with manual calculations.

Comment: Your post doesn't really contain a clear question, nor have you provided enough information for us to run your code (which is not written in the normal Mathematica style - it's too imperative). However, your problem is probably just loss of [precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NumericalEvaluationAndPrecision.html). The two "real data" values you gave will be interpreted as `MachinePrecision` numbers. Either use exact numbers or bump the precision up to say 30 by using ``71.02`30*^9`` and ``0.000247`30``. You should also try to use the built-in Fourier transform functions

Comment: So you've got all these As and Bs at the start but not in the next block. And you refer to e=1 and h=1 even though e and h aren't anywhere in the code. At a guess it looks like you are trying to solve for Fourier series coefficients or something???

Comment: Yes I agree that the code that I have written might not be the most elegant way to program in mathematica. I am actually new to the language. I am not trying to develop a Fourier transform, I am solving a partial differential equation of shell vibration using galerkin's method. Also the 'e' and the 'h' are actually in the eqC[m,n] and eqS[m,n] which have been declared earlier.

Comment: Let me rephrase what Mike asked, what variables in the above code are you setting to your "real values?" It is not clear which ones they are.

Comment: The `ExpandAll[Simplify` step just after the previous `ExpandAll` seems superfluous to me. You can add the division by 10^9 directly to the first step.

Comment: ok....let me put the whole code

Answer (score 7):

You can try and increase the precision of your calculations by globally setting, e.g., `$MinPrecision=50` and specifying your data values to a high precision using either `foo = SetPrecision[0.000247,50]` or using the shorthand `` 0.000247`50 ``.

Answer (score 2):

As a further alternative you could use `Rationalize[0.000247]` and then derive a numerical quantity later with `N[expr, prec]`. In M- if you give inexact input you get inexact output and for exact input you get exact output.